# String.contains(".") and Regex are evaluating as false when the length of the last word in a line exceeds 41

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a program which reads a line and checks it's structure. If the line has no dot present, it ignores it and moves to the next one that does have a dot (and if it's the first line with a dot found after one that didn't, it also ignores that one).

However, I ran into an issue where I noticed that long lines were being ignored. So I checked with the console to see where it was happening, and it showed me that the lines where the last word exceeded 41 were being flagged as "dotless" and were thus being ignored.

I was first using a regex to match the dot

```
if(errorCount < 1 && line.matches("^\\s{7}[^.]*$")){ //If a line doesn't have 7 whitespaces    from the start, it's an error, that's why my regex includes that.
  System.out.println("dot1 " + line); 
  pw.println(line);
  noPeriod = true;
  continue;  
}
```

I later changed that to use !line.contains(".") as the condition instead, but the same thing happens.

The following line evaluates correctly (dot is detected)

`77 RESu PIC A(2) VALUE aholaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.`

The same line with one more character evaluates as "dotless"

`77 RESu PIC A(2) VALUE aholaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.`

At first I thought it was an issue with the last word containing quotes, but it happens in any case, the only requirement is that the last word exceeds 41 in length.
There is no other condition that checks whether the last word is over 42 chars or not. Also, it's happening specifically on the last word. If I remove the space between VALUE and the word, the problem stops appearing.
a line like

`77 RESu PIC A(2) VALUEaholaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa.`

shows no issues.

Comment: I tested all three of your examples against your regex and they all return false for me as they should. Removing the '.' makes any of them return true. I suspect you must have code before this that changes the value in `line`.

Comment: With matches() you don't need to use ^ and $ because matches() checks for the entire line. I doubt this is your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's examine your regex.
`^\s{7}[^.]*$`

``^``
You first are asserting that the position of the match should start from the beginning of the string.

``{7}`` then of course match whitspace 7 times.

``[^.]*`` don't match a dot. **From zero to infinite.**
that means you encounter a dot you try match from the next character which will not work. as the anchor asserts we should be at the beginning.

``$`` And finally we must match till the end of the string or before a line break at the end of the string.

As of what you are trying to do is to make sure the whole of you string matches your regex. And obviously with a dot it won't. There cant be input restriction that tends to ignore your input as said. They will evaluate with sequence similar to above. Maybe that wasn't your problem. If you revist the java regex documentation or look at their source their is a complete algorithm that does not seem to induce such a random behaviour in any way whatsoever. It is therefore advised to use an external software like JRegex to test your regex before using them to ensure what you want to see is what you see.